# How to set the div width properly inside a flexbox?

Tags: html, css

I have this code

```html
<div style="display:flex; justify-content:space-between; width:100%">
    <div id="this">
       <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <input type="radio">
      <input type="radio">
   </div>
   <div>
      <p>Text</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to set the `#this` div width so that it is exactly the same size as the space-between attribute creates for it without push away the other elements. (The first puple section).

Basically what i want is to handle if the text is to long, by hidding it's overflow, but first I need to set it's width, and I want to show as much as its possible without pushing away other elements

If there's another way to handle long text that's fine too, just make it work like how I want.

[image]

I try to set the div `width`, `max-width` but can't figured out, each way the other elements are pushed away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use Flex:1; to set width to maximum available space between elements

You can see the detailed document about flex [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

```css
#this,#another{
  border:1px solid;
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex; justify-content:space-between; width:100%">
    <div id="this">
       <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <input type="radio">
      <input type="radio">
   </div>
   <div id ="another">
      <p>Text</p>
   </div>
</div>
```